# Media files with .mov are not playing in a cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, video, html5-video, cordova-ios

I am using Cordova to build my hybrid application. In this application i have a functionality to show preview of files before uploading them to server. For this when i am uploading video files and audio files recorded from device, it works if i am playing video/audio from device storage url. But it fails when i am binding the server url.

First i thought it is issue with content-type received from server so i changed it to video/quicktime. Obviously it didn't solved my problem.

Video files with mp4 extensions are playing perfectly. As iPad is returning .mov file and no other way to change video extension i cannot change encoding type.

My question is, what is issue when i am binding server url? it must not be issue with file codec as local file urls are playing without any issue. Is it a limitation of iOS/Cordova where we need to download and run the file instead of binding it to html5 video tag?

Is there any way where i can run these video files in an iOS/iPad device?

I am using html5  and  tags.

When url is binding to video/audio tag i am getting below issue in Xcode console

[image: Server API url]

Server response for video file with .mov format

[image: Server response]

When i run the same video on Mac chrome browser it works. Only in case of mobile app it does not play media file. File is downloading as well when url is accessed directly.

Please let me know if you need more information on this particular issue.

Details of platform

Cordova:

```
"cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
"cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
"cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^3.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^3.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
```

Answer (score 0):

Html5 has official support for a VERY limited number of codecs and containers. Mp4/h264/aac is basically the only file that is guaranteed to work in all browsers. Any other format and you must convert it.

Comment: Yeah i also did checked this previously what my question is i am able to play video from file system, but when same file uploaded to server it is not playing, request is rejected. I am able to download and on download i can play the same file.